# How to make a Responsive TextBox/Textarea where the fonts will resizable?

Tags: jquery, html, css, textbox, textarea

I want to make a responsive text-box/text-area where if i want to re-size the text-box/text-area the inside fonts will also re-size.

Waiting for the suggestions.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Can you be more specific and provide some example of the html and css you are using. However, this can be acheived by changing the font-size css property of the textarea within the corresponding media tags

Comment: Have you tried anything? You'd probably find more people willing to help you if you can show you've put some effort into finding a solution.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6FTdK/) you have shared the following should work. Basically we are just enclosing the entire textarea within the div-

- HTML

  ```
  <div id="resizable">
      <textarea rows="4" cols="40">This is a textarea. Test for resizing</textarea>
  </div>
  ```
- CSS

  ```
  textarea {
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
  }

  #resizable {
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
      font-size: 10px;
      background: #ccc;
  }
  ```
- JS

  ```
  $('#resizable').resizable({
      maxHeight: parseInt(200),
      maxWidth: parseInt(180),
      resize: function(evt, ui) {        
          var width1 = parseInt(ui.element.css('width')),
              height1 = parseInt(ui.element.css('height'));
          ui.element.css({
              'font-size': (width1/10)+'px',
              'line-height': (height1/10)+'px'
          });
      }
  });
  ```

Answer (score 0):

For your problem you might have to use javascript/jquery plugin are [fitext](http://fittextjs.com)

Or [BigText](http://www.zachleat.com/web/bigtext-makes-text-big/)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for giving me the suggestions. My proper requirement is something like this example- http://jsfiddle.net/6FTdK/ which functionality i need in a textbox/textarea.

`$('#resizable').resizable({
    maxHeight: parseInt(200),
    maxWidth: parseInt(180),
    resize: function(evt, ui) {

        var width1 = parseInt(ui.element.css('width')),
            height1 = parseInt(ui.element.css('height'));
        ui.element.css({
            'font-size': (width1/10)+'px',
            'line-height': (height1/10)+'px'
        });
    }
});`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `contenteditable` on your div: http://jsfiddle.net/6FTdK/97/

Then you can use ajax to submit.